# An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I am getting the following error on a dropdownlist control:

```
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

Here is the view code that it is crashing on:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PackageId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and here is the controller code where I get the data for the dropdownlist:

```
ViewBag.PackageId = new SelectList(db.Packages, "u_package_id", "package_nme");
```

and here is the package controller, in case it is needed:

```
public class Package
    {
        [Key]
        public int u_package_id { get; set; }

        public string package_type_cd { get; set; }

        public string package_nme { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

        public string modify_user_id { get; set;}

        public DateTime modify_dt { get; set; }

        public string package_category { get; set; } 

        public string i_package_nme { get; set; }

        public Guid msrepl_tran_version { get; set; }

        public string InvoicePackageName { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastModifyDate { get; set; }

        public string invoice_package_nme { get; set; }

        public Boolean InSTCUSAFlag { get; set; }

        public string InSTCUSADisplayedName { get; set; }

        public string InSTCUSADisplayedDescription { get; set; }

        public Boolean PrerequisiteFlag { get; set; }

        public Guid PrerequisiteID  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the details on the inner exception are... ?

Comment: @David, sorry but where would I find the inner exception details?

Comment: On the exception object.  Exceptions have a property called `InnerException` which is itself of type `Exception`.  Note that there could be multiple levels of exceptions in this structure.